# При вводе текста на сайте с iphone 5s глючит каретка ввода

Tags: css, ios, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, html-form

При вводе данных на iphone 5s в модальном окне в инпуте каретка ввода съезжает (не всегда) на поля ввода ниже или ещё куда-то, то есть получается, что находится не рядом с набираемым текстом. Это как-то исправляется? В чем может быть проблема? Если что, то верстку делали на bootstrap 4. Данная проблема из всех мобильников возникает похоже что только на iphone (тестировали на iphone 5s). 
Кто сталкивался с этим, как исправляется?

Comment: Такая же проблема, не пойму в чем может быть дело

Comment: Тоже сталкнулся с такой проблеммой на iphone 6s, на самописном модальном окне:(

Comment: [mcve] кто делать будет? // сс @Роман

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте добавить.

```
 input, input:before, input:after {
  -webkit-user-select: initial;
  -khtml-user-select: initial;
  -moz-user-select: initial;
  -ms-user-select: initial;
  user-select: initial;
 } 

 html,body{ -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important; 
/*overflow: auto !important; */
height: 100% !important; }
```